# My Visual Studio is rendering my web pages twice in browser

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Hi my VS is rendering my ASP.NET pages twice in the default IE browser when I press "View in browser" or "Start without debugging" button. This really puzzleds me.

Comment: @user370401 - What do you mean by renders them twice? It opens 2 windows/tabs? 2 requests are made?

Comment: Hi by rendering I mean it opens two windows to display the same page every time I try to view my pages in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problemo solved. It was due to the newly installed ZoneAlarm firewall. Don't ask me why.